# Sonarqube SVN Plugin fails with code E155007 'is not a working copy'

Tags: svn, sonarqube

Versions in use:

- **Sonarqube 5.1**
- **sonar-scm-svn-plugin 1.1**
- **JDK 1.7**

We migrated recently from Sonarqube 4.5 to 5.1. Since then we have problems with generated files, when SVN Plugin processes them:

```
05:24:03 Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155007: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cps-sonar/src/main/java/foo/Bar.java' is not a working copy
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:170)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:379)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:283)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:276)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.openAnchor(SVNWCAccess.java:171)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNStatusClient16.doStatus(SVNStatusClient16.java:374)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldGetStatus.run(SvnOldGetStatus.java:22)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldGetStatus.run(SvnOldGetStatus.java:13)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:363)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:422)
05:24:03    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:384)
05:24:03    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:72)
05:24:03    ... 57 more
```

The plugin is right, since the file is not in SVN. But instead of ignoring the file, the plugin fails.

Rather confusing, this bug seems to be fixed in *sonar-scm-plugin-1.1* since April, but it's supposed to be compatible with Sonarqube 5.1.1+, which had just been released in June: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SVN+Plugin . Do we need to migrate to 5.1.1 then?

A workaround so far is to ignore these files from Sonar-Analysis completely by exclusion patterns, which might look like a good idea in general, but I'd rather have even those files analysed, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is supposed to be fixed by sonarqube-scm-svn-plugin 1.1. And it is compatible with SQ 5.1, this is an error in update center I'll fix quickly.

Maybe the error is caused because your working copy format is too old. What is the version of your SVN client you used to do the checkout?

Comment: Actually, it is an incident on Jenkins. Checking the Subversion-Plugin, it says for SVNKit: *org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit:1.8.6*

Comment: If I remember correctly in Jenkins settings you can choose what will be the format version of SVN workspace. Please check and try to use a recent version.

Comment: Sorry, have been offline for a while. 

**We upgraded SVN on Jenkins and now it seems to work.** Thank you @Julien !